# Dead lock linux pipe

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-kernel, pipe

I want to learn how Linux pipes work! I wrote a small and easy program that use a pipe to communicate a string between parent and child process. However, the program results in a dead lock that I have not understood what is its cause.

Here is the code :

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100  

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pfd[2];
    int read_pipe=0, write_pipe=0; 
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf[SIZE]; 

    /* PIPE ***************************************
     * pipe() creates a pair of file descriptors, *
     * pointing to a pipe inode, and places them  *
     * in the array pointed to by filedes.    *
     * filedes[0] is for reading,         *
     * filedes[1] is for writing          *
     **********************************************/

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1) { 
        perror("pipe"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    read_pipe=pfd[0]; 
    write_pipe=pfd[1]; 

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) { 
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */

    char * hello = "I am a child process\n"; 
    sleep(1);  
    // wait until there is some data in the pipe
        while (read(read_pipe, buf, SIZE) > 0);
    printf("Parent process has written : %s\n", buf);
    write(write_pipe, hello, strlen(hello)); 
    close(write_pipe);
    close(read_pipe);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {                /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */

    char * hello = "I am a parent process\n";
    write(write_pipe, hello, strlen(hello));
    while (read(read_pipe, buf, SIZE) > 0); 
printf("Child process has written : %s\n", buf);

    close(write_pipe);       
    close(read_pipe);

    wait(NULL);             /* Wait for child */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) you'll find the proper mannipulation of PIPEs between parent and child. Your problem here is that the communication is not being correctly set-up.

The PIPE should be used to communicate in only one direction, so one process has to close the read descriptor and the other has to close the write descriptor. Otherwise what will happen is that the call to 'read'(both on the father and the son), since it can detect that there is another process with an open write descriptor on the PIPE, will block when it finds that the PIPE is empty (not return 0), until someone writes something in it. So, both your father and your son are getting blocked on their respective read.

There are two solutions to this:

.You create two PIPEs, one for the communication in each direction, and perform the initialization as explained in the link above. Here you have to remember to close the write descriptor when you are done sending the message, so the other process' read will return, or condition the loop to the count of bytes read (not to the return of read), so you won't perform another call when you read the whole message. For example:

```
int bread = 0;
while(bread < desired_count)
{
   bread += read(read_pipe, buf + bread, SIZE - bread);
}
```

.You create one PIPE as you did, and modify the flags on the read descriptor, using [fcntl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) to also have O_NONBLOCK, so the calls to read won't block when there's no information in the PIPE. Here you need to check on the return value of the read to know you received something, and go adding up until you get the full length of the message. Also you will have find a way to synchronize the two processes so they won't read messages that are not meant for them. I don't recommend you to use this option, but you can try it if you want using condition variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can tell if you see any of yout printf() outputs?
Anyway, if you want to establish a two way communication between your paent and child, yout should use two pipes, one for writing data form parent to child an the other for writing from child to parent. Furthermore, your read loops may be dangerous: if the data comes in two or more chunks the second read() overwrites the first portion (I've never seen tha happen with local pipes, but for example with sockets). And of course, yout  is not automatically null terminated after read(), so just printing int with "%s" may also cause problems. 
I hope that gives you some ideas to try.